# MATLAB - Can't call a built-in function from my own function

Tags: matlab, controls, simulink

I have a function `plot_exp_vs_sim.m` which has the following line in it:

```
which sim %simply to show debug output
sim('E05_model',t.time,[],[t.time,ref_input]);
```

Which calls the simulink model and provides some output. However, every time I try to run `plot_exp_vs_sim`, I get the following output:

```
built-in (/Applications/MATLAB_R2013b.app/toolbox/simulink/simulink/sim)
Undefined function or variable "sim".

Error in plot_exp_vs_sim (line 15)
sim('E05_model',t.time,[],[t.time,ref_input]);

Error in E05 (line 38)
plot_exp_vs_sim(t,ref_input,modelname,datafile);
```

So, the first line of the output shows that MATLAB knows exactly which function to call, yet isn't able to call it in the very next line. What's going on? I don't think I have any namespace conflicts!

Comment: does [this](http://shreyagarwal.blog.com/2012/04/17/undefined-function-or-method-sim-for-input-arguments-of-type-struct/) help?

Comment: Nope! Didn't seem to change anything when I added `%#function sim` to my code. If that piece is supposed to be in the `sim` function itself, I don't have access to it!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried calling `sim` from the command line? Does it work? Also worth trying `which -all sim` to check if you have multiple functions called `sim` and which one would be called first by default. Another thing to try would be to pass the complete path to the function `sim` in your script.